# How to properly setup a class structure to properly de-serialize XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

--UPDATED--

Actually, after looking at the code again, I should rephrase the question. Added more description below.

I have this XML structure that is returned from a web service, supposedly standard issue cXML structure. My issue is with a repeating `<Extrinsic>` nodes, that has a parameter name, which is, besides the value what differentiates them.

Like this:

```
    <ItemDetail>
      <UnitPrice>
        <Money currency="USD">1.53 </Money>
      </UnitPrice>
      <Description>ASPIRIN  81 MG CHW  90</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      <Extrinsic name="HCustomerNumber">0100074080</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="HPONumber">201</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="HOrderNumber">4413686057</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="HUserID">ABTGDEV</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="HLegacyCustomerNumber">055150912</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="LegacyItemNumber">198440</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="CustomerMaterialNumber"/>
      <Extrinsic name="ContractNumber"/>
      <Extrinsic name="NDC">00904628889</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="UPC">309046288893</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="Size">90</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="DrugFormPackSize">90.000</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="Prevent Sub">False</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="SHCCode"/>
      <Extrinsic name="DEPTCode"/>
      <Extrinsic name="GLCode"/>
      <Extrinsic name="SWP">3.62000</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="RetailPrice">0.00</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="RetailPriceOverride">0.00</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="TemporaryRetailPriceOverride">True</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="UDIF"/>
      <Extrinsic name="UDIFDesc"/>
      <Extrinsic name="Formulary"/>
      <Extrinsic name="SPLRouting"/>
    </ItemDetail>
```

How can I setup my class structure so this can be de-serialized properly? The class itself is rendered by the PetaPoco, so each of the `<Extrinsic>` nodes is a property of the class/field in the database. Or maybe it can't be done, and needs to be handled manually, I've been raking my head over this, and can't find a good automatic way.

--UPDATED --

This is what the class I am trying to de-serialize into

```
    public int syspohid { get; set; }
    public int syspodid { get; set; }
    public string pdvendor { get; set; }
    public string pdprefix { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdnumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdline { get; set; }
    public bool pdtaxable { get; set; }
    public bool pdfreightable { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string pdlocation { get; set; }
    public string pddoctor { get; set; }
    public string pdpatient { get; set; }
    public string pdlotnum { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> pdcasedate { get; set; }
    public bool pduseany { get; set; }
    public string pdvnitemid { get; set; }
    public string pdvnuofm { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdvnunit { get; set; }
    public string pddescript { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> pdvnprice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdvnqty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdrcvtype { get; set; }
    public string pdrcvline { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> sysprdid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pdvnorgqty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> sysshipid { get; set; }
    public string shipid { get; set; }
    public string shipdesc { get; set; }
    public string pdgl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> pdshipdt { get; set; }
    public string pdinternalid { get; set; }
    public string pdmanufacid { get; set; }
    public string pdndc { get; set; }
    public string pdpatchargeid { get; set; }
    public string pdupn { get; set; }
    public string entitycode { get; set; }
    public string deptcode { get; set; }
    public string classcode { get; set; }
    public string expencode { get; set; }
    public string cadduser { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dadd { get; set; }
    public string cedituser { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dedit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> taxpct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> invoiceqty { get; set; }
    public string auditinfo { get; set; }
    public string totenumber { get; set; }
    public string export { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> scheduledDrugIndex { get; set; }
    public string contractid { get; set; }
    public string refnum { get; set; }
```

The real question then becomes, how can I use the value of attribute *name* to properly de-serialize the xml. Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: And can you add the current code you are using to de-serialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a XML Schema (.xsd) file for the xml file coming back, you can generate classes with the XSD.exe command line tool.

[Link to XSD Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Alternatively,

If it were me though, I wouldn't deserialize it at all.  Instead I would parse it with XDocument/XElement objects etc.

For example, I'd create classes manually for everything and give them nicer features like,

```
public enum CurrencyType
{
    USD = 0,
    EUR = 1 //etc..
}
public class Money
{
    public CurrencyType CurrenyType { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public Money(XElement element)
    {
        if (element.Name.LocalName != "Money")
            throw new Exception(...);
        var aCurrency = element.Attribute("currency");
        this.CurrencyType = aCurrency == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(aCurrency.Value) ? CurrencyType.USD : (CurrencyType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyType), aCurrency.Value);
        this.Value = element != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Value) ? element.Value : 0;
    }
}
```

I would make one of those for each complex child element.  Then I would make a main one called ItemDetail that exposes those classes as properties.  In the constructor for ItemDetail I would load the xml to an Element, grab the money node, and instantiate the money class with the XElement for the money node, etc.

I generally go this route, because deserialization would give you a List of strings or a dictionary for your Extrinsic nodes, which I find to be combersome coding against it.  By doing it manually myself I can create properties for each Extrinsic value without having to figure out complex attribute mapping rules to make the deserializer do it.  Doing it this way generally results in better code (easier to follow and use) and is more flexible.

Comment: Thank you Ryios. This is a very interesting approach and I will most likely go this road, if no automatic way is found.

Comment: Before you do though, check to see if the webservice supports specific content types.  A lot of modern webservices default to xml, but if you specify the get content type as application/json it will give you json instead of XML. 

In that case you can use NewtonSoft' Json library to serialize the JSON to a dynamic object.  Or you can post the json on www.json2csharp.com and it will generate c# class code for you.  Note: You need to stringify the json before posting it on the side.  I do it in chrome console, var obj = JSON.strinify('paste json here'); obj; copy paste that into json2csharp.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using xsd.exe

```
D:\WorkSpace\dump>xsd myxml.xml
```

Or even taking next by using online tool such as

http://www.httputility.net/xsd-to-csharp-vb-class.aspx

In case of proper xml file this will generate easy to use C# classes for System.XML.Serialization.XMLSerializer to read and write XML